# Filter data starts with character - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have large set of data, and I want to filter the data which only start with certain character inside `Query`.

For example:-

```
AVTD1X4K1V0R01IA
AVTD1X4K1V0RXXF1
AVTD1X4K1V0RXXFA
AVTDMAIN1V0R03IA
AVTDMAIN1V0RXXFA
AWEWE23232323232
BLIVSE20122014X1
CA100U50VXSRCCCF
CA330U50VXSRCBCF
CA47UX63VXSRBBCX
```

In that data If I want to get starting with 'A' codes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `match` clause.

It will look like this based on your example

```
QUERY(A1:A11,"where A matches 'A.*'")
```

Change reference accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query(A:A,"select A where A like 'A%' ")
```